# How to get the 'path' to an embedded resource file in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, io, reference, embedded-resource

How would you move a resource file (like a custom embedded sqlite.db file) to internal storage? Or how do you get a reference to the actual embedded file for, say, the StreamReader constructor?

Comment: Have you found an answer? I'm looking how to get the path to an embedded ressource?

Comment: Try this for the actual embedded resource:  var res = Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.db); then write it to internal/external storage. Hope it helps.